# Using JavaMelody on a regular (non webApp) JVM

Tags: java, jvm, monitoring

My system is divided to 2 or 3 servers architecture, and only one server has a webApp

Since we use javaMelody to monitor the webApp server, is there a way to use on a regular, no-

webApp JVM, and if so, how can we access the data

Answer (score 0):

I would say include your application into a webapp (a war file for example) then deploy it in a server like Tomcat or Jetty. By the way, Tomcat or Jetty can be embedded.

Otherwise, there is currently no way to do this.

Comment: Embedding JavaMelody in a standalone app is now [documented](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#Embedding_in_a_standalone_app).